# Outlook Add-In VSTO invoke command 'remove paragraph formatting (CTRL-Q)'

Tags: vsto, outlook-addin

I want to invoke the Outlook command 'Remove Paragraph Formatting [(CTRL+Q)](https://lawyerist.com/39908/fix-formatting-fast-five-microsoft-word-tricks) programmatically at my Add-In. For instance is breaks the blue line on an e-mail reply. Is this possible? The command is not located at the CommandBar.

Jens

Answer (score 0):

> The command is not located at the CommandBar.

Office applications don't use command bars any longer. Instead, the Fluent UI is used.

In VBA you can use the [SendKeys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg278655(v=office.15).aspx) statement. But in .Net based add-ins you need to use Windows API functions for simulating the user's input. See the [SendInput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646310(v=vs.85).aspx) function for more information.

I'd suggest looking for another approach instead of sending the keystroke. For example, you can use the Word object model for editing the body programmatically.

Comment: Thanks. I'm already trying to change the ParagraphFormat programmatically, but is didn't work.

Comment: I've tried:

Word.Document d = (Word.Document) mi.GetInspector.WordEditor;
Word.Selection cs = d.Application.Selection;
cs.ClearParagraphAllFormatting();

Comment: Try asking a separate question in another forum thread. Moreover, it is related to Word, not Outlook.